# If we know $f\circ g(x)$ and $g \circ f(x)$ can we find unique $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?

Tags: functions

I was solving past year questions of an engineering entrance when I came across a question:
$f\circ g(x) = |\sin x|$ and $g\circ f(x) = \sin^2{\sqrt x}$, then find $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.
The most obvious answer would be $f(x) = \sqrt x$ and $g(x) = \sin^2 x$, and the other options did not satisfy the given definitions of their composites.
But is that the only solution? More generally, if $f\circ g(x)$ and $g\circ f(x)$ are known, can we find unique $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?

Comment: Your choices yield $g(f(x))=\sin^2\sqrt{x}$, which is different from your second equation.

Comment: For sure not.  $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ and $g(x) = \sin^2 x$ would make $g \circ f(x) = \sin^2 \sqrt{x}$.

Comment: I think the negative reaction to this question is a bit excessive, and have upvoted to compensate. (It's true that the question would be better if some context were included, but this is a kind of problem that - if one guesses the answer incorrectly - is difficult to see how to get started.)

Comment: Sorry for that mistake Robert Israel and Sanghcul Lee. I should have checked my question after I typed it.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no. For instance, imagine that $f(x)$ is bijective and $g(x)$ is just $f^{-1}(x)$. Then $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ could be known but you cannot tell what is $f$.

Comment: Why on earth did this get a downvote? It's perfectly accurate and quite clear. (In case someone didn't get it: in the situation above we have $f\circ g=g\circ f=id$. So any two distinct bijective functions yield a counterexample to the hope in the question. For example, take $f_1(x)=2x$ (so $g_1(x)={x\over 2}$) and $f_2(x)=x$ (so $g_2(x)=x$ also).)

Comment: What about this specific case where $f \circ g(x) =|\sin x|$ and $g \circ f(x) = \sin^2 {\sqrt x}$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple example why this is not possible: think about integer factorization which can be achieved in many ways. If you know the product $ab$ then $a$ and $b$ are not uniquely determined.

For instance $p=12$ then $(1,12),(2,6),(3,4)$ unordered couples work.

So setting $\begin{cases}f(x)=ax\\g(x)=bx\end{cases}\quad$ gets you to the issue seen above.

Let say that it get even worse when we consider the whole set of real functions.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you know $f \circ g = u$ and $g \circ f = v$.  Then
$$ f \circ v = f \circ g \circ f = u \circ f$$
Conversely, given $f$ that satisfies $f \circ v = u \circ f$, and assuming $f$ is invertible, you can define $g = f^{-1} \circ u$ and get
$$ \eqalign{ f \circ g &= f \circ f^{-1} \circ u = u\cr
g \circ f &= f^{-1} \circ u \circ f = f^{-1} \circ f \circ v = v\cr}$$
So basically the question is to what extent does the equation $f \circ v = u \circ f$ determine $f$?
The answer is basically, not very much.

Let's assume $u$ and $v$ are invertible, and there are no constraints of continuity.  Also, all functions map the same domain $D$ into itself.
We can partition $D$ into orbits of $v$, where an orbit of $u$ is  $O_v(x) = \{v^k(x): k \in \mathbb Z\}$ for some $x \in D$.  An orbit could be a single point (a fixed point of $u$), a finite set (a periodic orbit, where $v^p(x) = x$ for some positive integer $p$), or a two-sided infinite sequence.  Then the image of an orbit $O_v(x)$ of $v$ under 
$f$ is an orbit $O_u(f(x))$ of $u$, since $f(v^k(x)) = u^k(f(x))$.  Since we're assuming invertibility, 
$O_v(x)$ and $O_u(f(x))$ must have the same cardinality.    So $f$ maps fixed points of $v$ to fixed points of $u$, and periodic points of period $p$ for $u$ to periodic points of period $p$ for $v$.
But otherwise, we have a tremendous amount of freedom.  For example, we could swap two orbits, i.e. instead of
$f(v^k(a)) = u^k(b)$ and $f(v^k(c)) = u^k(d)$ we could make  $f(v^k(a)) = u^k(d)$ and $f(v^k(c)) = u^k(b)$, as long as $O_u(b)$ and $O_u(d)$ have the same cardinality.